# Q: on Lemma I.5.11 proof from Tourlakis 2003

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I'm unsure of the exact form of the I.H. in this case (the $\exists_x B \in Wff(M)$ rule).

I was thinking it could be $(B[x \leftarrow t])^\mathcal{J} = (B[x \leftarrow \bar i])^\mathcal{J}$, but it is possible that $w$ occurs free in $B$, so interpretation may not be defined ($B$ is not closed).

But in the proof he says $((B[w \leftarrow \bar j])[x \leftarrow \bar i])^\mathcal{J}$ comes from I.H., so does this mean that I.H. is:

> For any $m \in M$, $(B[w \leftarrow \bar m][x \leftarrow t])^\mathcal{J} = (B[w \leftarrow \bar m][x \leftarrow \bar i])^\mathcal{J}$ ?

Is this correct? Are we allowed to say something like this?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: But how does the I.H. know about the existence of some $j \in M$? Shouldn't the I.H. only assume 2 things: that (1) $\langle B,  \exists_w B \rangle \in \text{ExistsRule}$ and (2) $B$ satisfies the property being proven (namely substituting the imported term into $B$ interprets the same as importing the original term into $B$). How does substituting in $w \leftarrow \bar j$ come into this?

Comment: Because the semantical clause for the $\exists$ quantifier formalizes the intuition that to assert that $\exists x P(x)$ holds in $M$ amounts to saying that there is an object $j \in M$ such that $P$ holds of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line of the proof : the formula $\mathscr A$ is written in full.

Second step, the substitution $[x \leftarrow t]$ acts only on the formula $\mathscr B$ in the scope of the quantifier.

Third line : the semantic clause for the existential quantifier is applied (**Def.1.5.6**, page 55). Here we have an object $j \in M$ ad we use the corresponding *term* : $\overline j$.

Fourth line : the two substitutions commute (already proved).

Fifth line : the simultaneous substitution is transformed into two successive substitutions.

According to the statement of the **Lemma**, $\mathscr A$ has only $x$ free.

Thus, $\mathscr A [x \leftarrow t] := ((\exists w) \mathscr B)[x \leftarrow t])$ has no free variables.

When we remove the leading existential quantifier, formula $\mathscr B [x \leftarrow t]$ has only $w$ free, and thus $(\mathscr B [x \leftarrow t][w \leftarrow \overline j])$ has no free variables.

This in turn means that $\mathscr B [w \leftarrow \overline j]$ has only one free variable : $x$.

But formula $\mathscr B [w \leftarrow \overline j]$ has a "lower complexity" than $\mathscr A$, and thus we apply the Induction Hypotheses : **sixth line**.

This means that, according to the I.H., the formula $((\mathscr B [w \leftarrow \overline j])[x \leftarrow t])$ - that is, the formula $\mathscr B [w \leftarrow \overline j]$ with $x$ free where we have substituted the term $t$ in place of $x$ - has the same truth value of formula $((\mathscr B [w \leftarrow \overline j])[x \leftarrow \overline i])$, where $\overline i$ is the term associated to element $i \in M$ such that :

> $t^{\mathscr I}=i$.

Comment: I'm dumb, I was thinking of IH only on immediate predecessors. But IH should be applicable to any "lower complexity" wff. Thank you!